# post comments to google plus with api and fetch them

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, comments, google-plus

In facebook, we can specify a web page url and add comments to it, or fetch comments for it, with the Graph API.

Later we can fetch the comments for the page, using a sample code, and display them on my page, as a widget, using a javascript code.

Similarly, is it possible to setup comments for a web page virtually using google plus, and display them with a code, using the API ? I came across google plus client library for php, but not sure about how to achieve what i wanted, with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no public write API for Google+ or a way to bi-directionally integrate Google+ comments with an outside web page.

You **can** incorporate comments from a Google+ post onto your static page. Here are a couple of resources that can illustrate how:

- The full documentation for the Google+ read API is at https://developers.google.com/+/api/ and there are libraries for PHP and JavaScript at https://developers.google.com/+/downloads/
- http://little418.com/2011/12/google-comments-on-your-static-html-blog.html contains some examples about how to echo comments from a Google+ post.

Comment: I followed the code from http://little418.com/2011/12/google-comments-on-your-static-html-blog.html

Comment: @MariaMeh - I would suggest you start a new question on SO asking your question specifically, giving the code you're using (minus any secret keys), and any errors it is returning. Trying to help you this way will be extremely difficult.